# PHP read chunk files anomaly

Tags: php

I have a Server part of a Webservice which send to me for parameters: offset and maxLen (see file_get_contents()), an encoded content from a file. From client side i try to get this content and save into another file. My client side code is like that:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalFileSize + 1;$i+=50000) {
   file_put_contents('ex.zip', $server->download($i, 50000), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

On the service side i just use file_get_contents to give that part of file which is requested. The problem is that dimension of two files are not the same and also md5 is different.

I know what is the size of server file.

Can you tell me, please, what is it wrong?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like opening both files in a text/hex editor and seeing what the differences are? Plus, file offsets generally start at `0`. you're starting at `1`, so possibly you're skipping the very first byte in the file...

Comment: Yep, i think my idea with for is not a very good one, but i am not sure why. The original file have size: 4063719 and my file has 4063718

Comment: well, there you go. the difference is **ONE** byte. try starting `$i=0`.

Comment: I try that now the file size is correct, but md5 is still different.

Comment: so compare both files and see how the contents differ.

Comment: i wil try to compare both zip file :)

Comment: I tried and i was using command md5 on file path not on file  content. I am sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70051/discussion-between-osoma-and-marc-b).